# Trouble setting up a transparent proxy

Tags: linux, iptables, proxy, squid

I have been trying without success to setup a transparent proxy on a router like computer. Most examples that I have found don't have the gateway and proxy on the same computer, so I may be looking at the wrong examples. Here is how my 'router' computer is setup:

- It acts as a wireless AP and has two LAN ports (only using one LAN port at the moment)
- It has a DHCP and DNS server set up on it
- Dansguardian and squid are fully setup (I have tested both with telnet and squidclient)
- NAT through iptables is all set and works fine.

My current iptables setup script (yes, it is very simple and allows too much. I will lock it down much better after I get the transparent proxy working):

```
LAN="wlp4s0"
WAN="enp3s0"

PROXY_PORT="8080"

iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t mangle -X

#handle unmatched traffic
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP

### Allow Loopback
iptables -A INPUT  -i lo -s 127.0.0.0/8 -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -s 127.0.0.0/8 -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j ACCEPT

#rules for NAT
iptables -A FORWARD -o $WAN -i $LAN -s 192.168.0.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $WAN -j MASQUERADE
```

Here are the different rules I have tried:

```
#I quickly get a 'website unavailable' message with this one
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i $LAN -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port $PROXY_PORT
```

And

```
#Requests timeout with this one
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i $LAN -s 192.168.0.0/24 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port $PROXY_PORT
```

And

```
#Requests timeout with this one also
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i $LAN -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.0:$PROXY_PORT
```

Anyone have any ideas what I am doing wrong? Am I missing other rules or have existing rules that mess it up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The fact that the first rule, `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i $LAN -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port $PROXY_PORT` was not timing out but was returning with an error right away was the key.

Dansguardian as set to listen on 127.0.0.1, but not 192.168.0.1(the ip address of the server). My telnet tests before used 127.0.0.1. Once I tried testing with telnet to 192.168.0.1, I quickly figured out the problem.